# Algorithms for generating $A_n$ and $S_n$ from specific generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems, computational-algebra

Is there a simple algorithm to generate the elements of the alternating group $A_n$ in terms of some small set of generators?

For example, when $n = 4$, I'm looking for an algorithm whose *output* is a generating set, say $\{ a = (1,2,3), b = (1,2)(3,4) \}$ together with a list of 12 words in $a$ and $b$ that represent that elements of $A_4$.

What about such an algorithm for the symmetric group? For example, when $n = 4$ an algorithm that outputs, for example, $\{ a = (1,2,3,4), b = (1,2) \}$ and a listing of $S_4$ as 24 words in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: If you want an algorithm that will work for _arbitrary_ generating sets, that can be actively difficult (for instance, that would solve most Rubik's Cube-style puzzles).  If you want an algorithm that will work in terms of a generating set that it can provide, that's much easier.

Comment: Having the algorithm choose an easy generating set is OK. I'll update my question.

Comment: I can turn this into a proper answer when I get home (and can flesh it out with a few details so it isn't link-only), but this is covered in vol. 4 of Don Knuth's _The Art Of Computer Programming_, specifically section 7.2.1.2, 'Generating all Permutations'; you can find the original fascicle text at http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc2b.pdf .  In particular, there are some 'Gray Code' style algorithms for $S_n$ where by taking every other answer you get an algorithm for $A_n$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - But does the algorithm you have in mind express $S_n$ in terms of some generating set? I'm looking for something a little different than just enumerating everything: I'd like to enumerate the elements of these groups in terms of some small generating set.

Comment: David: it does, though the lengths of elements could be comparable to the size of the group itself (since each group element is generally built from applying one generator or the other to the previous element (for instance, in 'Ringing Changes'-style enumerations, one alternates a particular two-element transposition with repeated applications of an $n$-cycle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the symmetric group $S_n$, you can generate it with the two elements $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(1,2,\dots,n)$: By conjugating $a$ by $b^k$, you get $(1+k,2+k)$; this allows you to swap any two adjacent elements $1,\dots,n$ using only the generators $a$ and $b$. Given an arbitrary permutation, you can then bring it to the identity permutation by using the bubble-sort algorithm; if you keep track of the steps in this process, it will show you how to express the permutation as a word in $a$ and $b$.

This technique can also be adapted to show that the alternating group $A_n$ can be generated by two elements, $a=(1,2,3)$ and $b=(1,2,\dots,n)$ (if $n$ is odd) or $b=(2,\dots,n)$ (if $n$ is even).

Comment: Note, BTW, that the $\Theta(n^2)$ bound you get here on the maximum length of words is optimal (modulo constant factors) for these generators.  See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102737/diameter-of-symmetric-group - I don't know how much better you can do with a 'constant' set of generators.